# createElement background image

Tags: javascript, background-image, createelement

I am trying to create a table width javascript and createElement().
My problem is that it does not set any background image (just plain white).
However, if I set the innerHTML of the  to an image tag with same path, it works!

```
create : function () {
    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    for(i in this.map) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for(j in this.map[i]) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var cell = this.map[i][j];
            td.style.color = "red";
            console.log("gfx/tile_"+this.backgrounds[cell]+".png");
            td.style.backgroundImage = "url(gfx/tile_"+this.backgrounds[cell]+".png);";
            td.innerHTML = "j";
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    this.gameDOMelm.appendChild(tbody);
}
```

I also have another problem that there's space between each ROW in the table.
Here's the DOM Element I'm appending to:

```
<table id="gameField" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
```

And the CSS

```
    * {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    td {
        min-width: 32px;
        min-height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
```

These problems occur both in Chrome and FF @ ubuntu 11.04.
No errors shows in javascript console.

- jack

Comment: What CSS do you see in Firebug?

Comment: I see the "color:red;" is applied. I see the one a posted in question. No background image however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `"url('gfx/tile_"+this.backgrounds[cell]+".png')"` (with single quotes around the URL).

Comment: That worked. I was sure I'd already tried that several times. But yeah - must have missed something! It actually also fixed my rowspacing problem! Thanks alot!!